# Intercepting syscall in a shared object (dynamically linked)

Tags: binary-analysis, x86, linux, dynamic-linking, system-call

Ditto. Any technique that allows to intercept sys calls issued from a shared object file? At runtime, the shared object is `dlopen`'ed by main().

One candidate is to use static binary rewriting (e.g. dyninst). But as I tried, it throws an error (saying about `r_debugCheck()` failed). Wondering if anyone had experiences in this task.

Comment: What about pin and frida ?

Comment: Can you name an example binary and shared object (including an exemplary syscall) from Ubuntu 14? It would help me to verify my solution before posting it.

Comment: @ws pin and frida are dynamic rewriting techniques which work at runtime. but OP prefers static rewriting tools...

Comment: @stackoverflowwww one simple example is to have a main() calling dlopen to open the shared object and call its function after dlsym. In the shared object, for instance, it calls malloc which might further call brk() and mmap(); which are what I want to intercept.

Comment: @Richard could you point me to a concrete specific binary? I tried to find one but the dynamically loaded libs of my samples did not call malloc (or any other functions calling mmap or brk). Alternatively, you could give a link to a custom-made sample (source code + a coplete command or Makefile to compile and link it.).